# Fixed div on mobile is not fixed

Tags: html, css, mobile

I need to have an action bar fixed to the bottom of the screen.

The following CSS works well in desktop mode :

```html
        <div class="slds-p-around--large actions">

            <lightning-button-stateful
                    label-when-off="Check All"
                    label-when-on="Uncheck All"
                    label-when-hover="Uncheck All"
                    icon-name-when-off="utility:check"
                    icon-name-when-on="utility:close"
                    icon-name-when-hover="utility:close"
                    selected={selected}
                    onclick={handleMasterSelection}>
            </lightning-button-stateful>

            <button class="slds-button slds-button--success" onclick={handleApprove}>Approve</button>
            <button class="slds-button slds-button--destructive" onclick={showConfirmationModal}>Deny</button>
        </div>
```

```css
.actions{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #F3F2F2;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    height: 8vh;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

But in mobile mode it doesn't work, the div isn't fixed. I have to scroll to the bottom of the page to see it.
Any clue about that?

Comment: could you share the rest of the code or JS fiddle to test it

Comment: Post your html code as well that is associated with that css code you've provided

Comment: remove left property and test again

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I updated with the html code. Removing left property did not change anything.

Comment: What you have is perfectly working with different screens, try to remove other class names for the main div and see if they are affecting it, I tested what you have and it's working for both mobile and desktop

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer so I think the error comes from the framework's context

Comment: You probably have a media query removing the fixed position for mobiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by Salesforce's Mobile App Web container, whose custom scroll prevents `position: fixed` to work correctly.

After a thorough investigation, I found out that the issue is caused by Salesforce’s mobile app web container, which does not use native window scrolling but instead, translates the content using CSS like translate3d on the swipe down event.

I don’t know why they did that since it breaks the position : fixed CSS among other things.

The workaround I found was the following :
Set something like

```css
max-height : 90vh ; // Can be changed to suit the size you want your « fixed » element to have left
overflow-y : scroll ;
```

on the content of your page the have your content scrolling without scrolling the page itself. You can then put the content which you want fixed at the top or Bottom of the content, which will imitate the behaviour of a position fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `background-color: #000;` and remove `left: 0;` it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just edited as you suggest but it doesn't work, the behavior is the same

Comment: some other class is causing the problem. You have to share the full code via http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: It won't work on JS Fiddle because I use a Web Components framework which isn't supported on JSFiddle

Comment: See here https://jsfiddle.net/ujjawalpoonia/dx0uLszc/ it is working fine. So some other class is causing the problem.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer so I think the error comes from the framework's context